# xcode 7.3 Chinese localization does not work with iOS 8.x

Tags: swift, localization

I am building an app, this app support multiple languages with English, Chinese Simplified,Chinese Traditional (TW), Thai and Indonesian.
for iOS 9.x => it works correctly for all languages.
for iOS 8.x => Chinese does not work (both simplified and traditional). it works with Indonesian and Thai.
I am using xCode 7.3.
I have no idea now.
What can I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.
1. open the root folder of my project, i see 2 folders zh-Hans-CN.lproj and zh-Hant-TW.lproj (you can find zh.lproj in your case)
2. change the name to zh-Hans.lproj and zh-Hant.lproj
3. in the xcode you will see some errors because the paths are changed.
4. open .xcodeproj with sublime or any text editors.
5. find the old paths with -CN.lproj and -TW.lproj and change it as you did in step2.
6. build and enjoy it.
Hope it helps someone :)